# Java trying to loop

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

i am trying to loop something so that it will restart after a few minutes.

here is my code

```
private static boolean online = false;

public static boolean isStreamLive() {
  {  firstloop: if(online == false) {
     try {
         URL url = new URL(  insertChannel(TWITCH_STREAM, "nyankosaan") );
         URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ));
         String inputLine = br.readLine();
         br.close();
         JsonObject jsonObj = JsonObject.readFrom(inputLine);
         return ( jsonObj.get("stream").isNull() )?false:true;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    } else {
     if(isStreamLive() == true);
     try {
         continue;

    } finally {

    }



    }

return online;
}

 }
 }
```

for some reason the continue has an error saying "continue cannot be used outside of a loop". can anyone help me figure out why its saying that?

Comment: Do you have a loop in your code? If not, what do you expect `continue` to do?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) carefully.

Comment: `if(isStreamLive() == true);` should not have a semicolon...

Comment: I recommend that you review Java keywords, such as [looping](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm), as well as [try-catch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm), because you have no loop, and your using a try statement without a catch, and no exception is thrown by `continue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of loops in java

1) for loops:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
   //...
}
```

2) While loops

```
while (conditon) {
    //...
}
```

3) Do- While loops

```
do {
    //...
} while (condition);
```